# Application blinks when adding MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a multipane main activity.Its layout is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/multipane_half_padding"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation"
        android:name="com.armsoft.mtrade.fragments.NavigationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_detail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/multipane_half_padding"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_frame" />
```

And than I add another fragment to fragment_container_detail with

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/planned_routes_map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<com.armsoft.mtrade.widget.BidirectionalDatePicker
    android:id="@+id/bidirectional_date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/planned_routes_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

layout.

When pressing menu item  I add a MapFragment to planned_routes_map_container 
and my application starts blinking.
How can I fix this problem?